# Output display stay longer on screen

Tags: javascript

The output text display for a second and then gone forever...is there a way to make it stay?

```
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function input(){
            var input_taker = document.getElementById('email').value;
            document.getElementById('display').innerHTML = input_taker;
        }
    </script>


</head>

<form method="post" action="#">
<input type="text" name="email" placeholder="email@example.com" id="email"  onchange="input()">
<input type="submit" name="save" value="save">
```

Comment: Are you saying it's gone after... they stop typing? They submit the form? Where is this element with an ID of 'display'?

Comment: Sorry I am completely a newbie with zero programming experience. I mean when i hit the save button, the email address only display for a second and gone. I want to make it stay on screen for longer.

Comment: Also, why do you have `<form method="post" action="#">` ? I am pretty sure this will just reload the same page. Maybe you want this, but as the page is reloading, the changes made to the DOM inside of the input function will be gone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you hit the save button it's probably trying to POST your `form` - you can remove the `form` element and your code will pretty much work - if all you want to do is display the `text` input's value elsewhere on the screen.

Here's an example:

```js
function input() {
  var input_taker = document.getElementById('email').value;
  document.getElementById('display').innerHTML = input_taker;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" name="email" placeholder="email@example.com" id="email" onchange="input()">

<input type="submit" name="save" value="save">
<br/>
<div id="display" onchange="input()">
```